# Java scanner input mismatch when using space in input

Tags: java, input, java.util.scanner, inputmismatchexception

I am using the scanner in java and am trying to enter a space in my input for option 2 (removing a user from my hashmap) but when I add a space in my answer I get an InputMismatchException. while researching I came across this thread [Scanner Class InputMismatchException and Warnings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25877199/scanner-class-inputmismatchexception-and-warnings) that says to use this line of code to solve the issue: `.useDelimiter(System.getProperty("line.separator"));` i have added this and now my option 2 goes into a never-ending loop of me inputting data. Here is my code:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);

        AddressBook ad1 = new AddressBook();
        String firstName="";
        String lastName="";
        String key="";
        int choice=0;
      do{
        System.out.println("********************************************************************************");
        System.out.println("Welcome to the Address book. Please pick from the options below.\n");
        System.out.println("1.Add user \n2.Remove user \n3.Edit user \n4.List Contact \n5.Sort contacts \n6.Exit");

          System.out.print("Please enter a choice: ");
         choice = scan.nextInt();

        if(choice==1){
            //Add user
            System.out.print("Please enter firstname: ");
            firstName=scan.next();
            System.out.print("Please enter lastname: ");
            lastName=scan.next();
            Address address = new Address();
            key = lastName.concat(firstName);
            Person person = new Person(firstName,lastName);
            ad1.addContact(key,person);
            System.out.println("key: " + key);
        }

        else if(choice==2){
            //Remove user
            System.out.println("Please enter name of user to remove: ");
            scan.useDelimiter(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
            key=scan.next();
            System.out.println("name:" + key);
            ad1.removeContact(key);  
        }

        else if(choice==3){
            //Edit user
        }

        else if(choice==4){
            //List contact
            ad1.listAllContacts();

        }

       else if(choice==5){
            //Sort contacts
        }
      }while(choice!=6);
    }
}
```

The reason why I need to use a space is to remove a user from my hashmap I need to enter their full name as the key is a concatenation of their last and firstname, any help will be appreciated

Comment: You should discard previous line by using `scan.nextLine();` instead of `useDelimiter()`

Comment: that does not seem to make a difference

Comment: Do it before print line and don't save return value anywhere.

Comment: Thank you, it works fine now, would I have to do that every time I need to scan a full line then?

Comment: You can do it after `choice = scan.nextInt();` then you don't have to do it in every if-else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`nextInt()` behaves similar to `next()` that is when it read a line it places the cursor behind it.

Example:
You give 6 as input

```
6 
 ^(scanner's cursor)
```

So next time when you call `nextLine()`. It will return the whole line after that cursor which is empty in this case.

To fix this issue you need to call an extra `nextLine()` so that the Scanner closes the previous line it was reading and move on to the next line.

You could do this

```
System.out.print("Please enter a choice: ");
choice = scan.nextInt(); // Reads the int
scan.nextLine(); // Discards the line
```

And in choice 2 since you want full name of user you could just use `nextLine()` to get whole line along with space.

```
//Remove user
System.out.println("Please enter full name of user to remove: ");
key=scan.nextLine();
System.out.println("name:" + key);
ad1.removeContact(key);
```

Or you could do something similar to what you did in choice 1

```
System.out.print("Please enter firstname: ");
firstName=scan.next();
System.out.print("Please enter lastname: ");
lastName=scan.next();
key = lastName.concat(firstName);
System.out.println("name:" + key);
ad1.removeContact(key);  
scan.nextLine(); // This is will make sure that in you next loop `nextInt()` won't give an input mismatch exception
```